# Finding backgroundTimeRemaining on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

My iOS application has some data-processing that run on background threads.  The data-processing can take some time to complete, so I regularly check backgroundTimeRemaining to see if I need to tidyup and stop the data-processing before the App is killed.

For this I call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]
```

With latest XCode this now causes a run-time error:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication backgroundTimeRemaining]
```

Is there any way to get the backgroundTimeRemaining without adding calls back to the Main Thread every time?  That seems more painful than it should be...??

Thx
Mike

Comment: This seems to be a known bug: http://www.openradar.me/33541766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIApplication is part of UIKit.  From the documentation of [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) it states:

> Important
>   Use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread or main dispatch queue, unless otherwise indicated. This restriction particularly applies to classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

So this call needs to be on the main thread.